# How can I get View below Material Bottom TabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

[image: Custom View below the tab view]

What I want to achieve is like this

So There is a Bottom tab navigator and below that, I want to show my custom view.

Is there any way so I can achieve it?

bottom Tab code

```
const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: Home,
    },

    Profile: {
      screen: Profile,
    },
    ...
  },
);

export const Root = createStackNavigator({

  Tabs: {
    screen: Tabs,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    }
  },

  ...

},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Tabs',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is actually not possible using createBottomTabNavigator, you can create a Horizontal FlatList for creating a tab Bar like this :

````
  <FlatList
                horizontal
                keyExtractor={item => item}
                extraData={this.state}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                ref={r => (this.tabList = r)}
                data={tabsArray}
                renderItem={this.renderTabHeader}
              />
    ```

and then add renderTabHeader method like this : 


renderTabHeader = ({ item, index }) => {
      return (
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
          <Text
            onPress={() => {
              if (index !== 4) this.changeIndex(index);
              else
                this.props.navigation.navigate('screenName');
            }}
            style={{
              paddingHorizontal: 16,
              paddingVertical: 8,
              textAlign: 'center',
              color:
                this.state.selectedTab === index
                  ? color.primaryTextColor
                  : color.inactiveTextColor,
              fontFamily: font.medium,
            }}>
            {item}
          </Text>
          {this.state.selectedTab === index ? (
            <View
              style={{
                height: 2,
                width: '100%',
                backgroundColor: 'white',
              }}
            />
          ) : null}
        </View>
      );
  };
````

Answer (score 0):

You can make your custom component and use it like this in navigation:

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
<Tab.Navigator tabBar={(props) => <BottomNavigationBar {...props} />}>
  <Tab.Screen name="blabla" .........
</Tab.Navigator>
```

the `BottomNavigationBar` is your component and you can make it as you wish